# dimension mismatch in args to gemm python

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano

I am using theano for the first time. I am using this [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html#mlp) code, and I defined some shared variables, this way:

```
train_set_x_sh = theano.shared(np.asarray(train_set_x))
train_set_y_sh = theano.shared(np.asarray(train_set_y))

train_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=cost,
    updates=updates,
    givens={
        x: train_set_x_sh[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: train_set_y_sh[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

However, when I want to use these shared variables I've got this error:

```
ValueError: dimension mismatch in args to gemm (20,52)x(784,500)->(20,500)
Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuSubtensor{int32:int32:}.0, W)
Toposort index: 14
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix),CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(20, 52), (784, 500)]
Inputs strides: [(52, 1), (500, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuElemwise{Composite{tanh((i0 + i1))}}[(0, 0)](GpuDot22.0, GpuDimShuffle{x,0}.0)]]
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code ? are you using the code from the [tutorials](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/index.html) ? There is a clear dimension mismatch when computing the cost.

Comment: @uyaseen I just post the link to the tutorial code that I am using. Thank you

Comment: If you haven't changed the tutorial's code apart from what you have mentioned then you should get a different error instead of 'dimensionality mismatch', are you sure you have not made any other changes, also you are using mnist from [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/deep/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz)

Comment: also `train_set_x` is already a theano shared variable, you don't need to create a shared variable again, `load_data()` from [logistic regression's](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) tutorial does that already.